# Correlate between OOMKilling event and the actual pod killed

Tags: python, kubernetes, monitoring, kubectl

I'm using the [Kubernetes events API](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/python/blob/master/kubernetes/docs/EventsV1Api.md) to check if my cluster have any [OOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out_of_memory) events. In the case it does, I'm sending an alert regarding this event.

Right now the only information I have to send is the node name, the event name, the reason (OOMKilling for example) and the message the event has which for OOM usually have the process killed and the name of the command line in the process, for example: `"(combined from similar events): Memory cgroup out of memory: Killed process 3448515 (stress) total-vm:1536784kB, anon-rss:522964kB, file-rss:332kB, shmem-rss:0kB, UID:0 pgtables:1064kB oom_score_adj:871"`

I want to be able to pinpoint which pod is being killed exactly *and* which pod, if possible caused this OOM (which depending on priority configurations might be two different pods).

The only way I can see right now to do this, is to correlate between the `OOMKilling` event and the `BackOff` event that a pod should have when an OOM happens. But this feels like it can lead to some wrong heuristics and timing issues (did I send the API call too soon?

Maybe I only see the OOM event now, and not the `BackOff` event), and even if I do this, I can only find the killed pod, and not the culprit of the event—when the culprit pod has a higher priority class, and killing one other pod is enough to satisfy the memory requirements in the node.

Is there anything in the API I am missing? Maybe some other API I can use to find this?

I also considered using [kube-state-metrics](https://github.com/kubernetes/kube-state-metrics), as they have a metric for OOM events, but with my system structure, KSM does not fully help me, but in the KSM they have the OOM events per POD and not per Node, so this should be also possible.

Using events API and the core API of k8s project to retrieve the OOM events.

I looked at KSM and on various other sources to try and get which pod is the culprit on the node that has the OOM event.